# Update AD User From CSV Based on EmployeeID Attribute

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am attempting to update AD users based on their employeeID number. It is a reliable key field for our organization.

Every user in this case was created with an employeeID attribute. I am using the same csv for the initial creation (New-ADuser) of users (only setting less attributes), as I am the update (Set-ADUser) of users.

Most of this is pretty straightforward and sourced mostly from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c04bbf55-8186-4b12-ba12-df9c9984982f/update-active-directory-attributes-using-employee-id-as-a-primary-key?forum=winserverDS).  I successfully import my csv, and can print my variables. My resulting message indicates that when I execute my If/Else, that the "User with ID is not found, or more than one is found", both of which aren't true. I believe my issue to be in this line:

```
$UserID = Get-ADUser employeeID=$EmployeeId
```

Here is the entirety of the script. What am I doing wrong here?

```
# Import AD Module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Import CSV into variable $userscsv
$ADUsers = Import-Csv -Path C:\Scripting\CSVs\UpdateADUsers.csv


foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
#Retrieve info from CSV
$Title = $User.Title
$Department = $User.department
$Office = $User.Office
$EmployeeId = $User.EmployeeId
$Manager = $User.manager
$Company = $User.Orglevel02

#get user DN
$UserDN = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "EmployeeId=$EmployeeId"

If ($UserDN.Count -eq 1)
 {
        # Use the Set-ADUser cmdlet to assign the new attribute values.
        Set-ADUser -Identity $UserDN -Replace @{title=$Title;physicalDeliveryOfficeName=$Office;manager=$Manager}
    }
    Else {"User with ID $ID either not found, or more than one user found."}
}
```

Comment: You are using employeeID and not employeeNumber right?

Comment: Correct. A trip to the attribute editor tells me so.

Answer (score 2):

```
$UserDN = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(EmployeeId=*$EmployeeId*)"
```

Comment: I initially tried with that syntax, minus the *wildcard. Results still the same, implying User with ID 1234567 either not found, or more than one user found.

Comment: Add `write-host $UserDN.count` to find out if its none or more than one. Also worth doing a write-host on $employeeid to make sure it does contain what you think it does.

Comment: Try `(EmployeeId=*$EmployeeId*)` as maybe there are some whitespace characters around it in AD?

Comment: When creating the export CSV from the HRIS system in R, I eliminated the white space around everything. Sure of that, but I included the *___* regardless. As for write-host $UserDN.count, here is the response:    'code'

If False

        # Use the Set-ADUser cmdlet to assign the new attribute values.
        Set-ADUser -Identity $UserDN -Replace 
@{title=$Title;physicalDeliveryOfficeName=$Office;manager=$Manager}
'code'

Comment: Could there be whitespace in the field in AD though?

Comment: Not a drop of white-space around the fields in AD.

Answer (score 2):

[Marks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42843201/3829407) contains the major correction needed in your filter.

Each of your search criteria at a minimum must be in a set of parenthesis. Like in the example given on [ldapexplorer.com](http://www.ldapexplorer.com/en/manual/109010000-ldap-filter-syntax.htm)

> ```
> Equality: (attribute=abc)     , e.g. (&(objectclass=user)(displayName=Foeckeler)
> ```

Your current example has bad syntax since it is missing braces but does not constitute a failure of the cmdlet, so, nothing (`$null`) is returned. You have a response to this in comments

> I initially tried with that syntax, minus the *wildcard. Results still the same, implying User with ID 1234567 either not found, or more than one user found.

What if you hardcode an employeeID in there for testing?

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(EmployeeId=12345)"
```

If that works then that tells me something is wrong with your source file. Leading or trailing whitespace or perhaps hidden characters? Either way look at the source to be sure and if you have to use `.Trim()` for testing as you might not initially see the problem.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(EmployeeId=$($EmployeeID.Trim()))"
```

Comment: I don't have that system in front of me as it is test and abstracted somewhere on the network, but I was able to hardcode the ID at one point after changing syntax a bit. I was even able to go back to drawing out the EmployeeID for the users. More tomorrow, when I can get on that system.

Comment: @Scottieie Care to share?

Comment: Through more searching, I found a code snippet that rectified my issue here: [link] (http://serverfault.com/questions/707776/bulk-update-ad-attribues-with-employee-id-as-matched-key). I ended up using the $_.psobject.properties which I believe gets the AD attributes for each user, compares the EID in AD with that of the CSV. Then proceeds to set the new attributes using Set-ADUser.

Comment: All the filter does in the backround is convert to an ldap filter. That should be no different then what you are already doing except that the example you just gave has different variable names from your original post.

Comment: @Mark I was working through the syntax for how to link in SO. The mini markdown eludes me. I get an F in Stack Overflow. This filter seems to work:    

'$user = Get-ADUser -Filter {employeeID -eq $eid}'

Comment: *cough* i'm Matt. For links in comments use `[text](http:\\supersite.com)`. For plain code use backticks around the code.

Comment: Thanks for the information on what is happening in the background. This scripting is somewhat new to me, so I continue to be amazed when things work.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to pay homage to Mark as well to clue him in on the filter issue. I knew you would be notified as you were the previous poster. 
[text](http:\\www.site.com).
    'here: is "some" code <- merge(x, y, by.all=TRUE)'...clueless.

Comment: Sorry your slahes are backwards for your link (my bad). backticks =/= single quotes. Use the character that likely shares a key with your tidle.